# Storing a lot of files in the database

Tags: sql-server

We got `UploadedFiles` database table where a lot of files (400k at the moment) are stored.

Would we get any performance benefit if we move actual file data (varbinary field) in a separate table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your version of SQL, you could take a look at FILESTREAM:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could use partitions and put that field in a different partition.  Here are some reference links:

**Note** when creating partitions to optimize performance place each partition on different physical disks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28SQL.90%29.aspx

http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/partitioning.htm

---

OR store the file in the file system and keep a reference to the location in a varchar field.

Comment: +1 for storing a reference to the file location.  It's usually the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on SQL Server 2000/2005 and don't have filestream available, don't forget about the ability to create separate filegroups and data files.

Configuring user filegroups and placing them on separate physical drives (or LUNs) from system database objects with result in better performance. This also gives you more flexibility with backup and restore operations. More info here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2009/05/21/sql-server-best-practices-setting-a-default-filegroup.aspx